# How to copy (not move) one git branch with merges to another

Tags: git, merge, git-cherry-pick, git-cherry

I am trying to reorganize GIT repository, which is full of unorganized branches. Now we want to make some structure there (devel, production, features, ...branches) and delete/squash many small changes too. But something is needed to keep yet as it is, as there are people working on it.

So I created the big structure, squashed old things together (nobody longer interested in small typo fixes years old) and basically fixed everything to begin of this year.

But now the problem came - some branches are active, cannot be squashed fully, cannot be deleted/moved (until new schema proves to work for some time) and contains a lot of small merges inside, like this:

```
  jacks_branch   
    A-B-C-F-G-H-I-J-M-N-O-P ...
            \D-E/    \K-L/
```

I would like to COPY this on top of appropriate feature branch, like

```
  feature_123
    XX-YY
  =>
    XX-YY-C'-F'-G'-H'-I'-J'-M'-N'-O'-P' ...
                \D'-E'/     \K'-L'/
```

(the schema is more complicated, this is the problematic part)

I would like to do something like

```
git checkout feature_123
git cherry-pick C..P
```

but it results on conflict on all those merges

```
error: could not apply E
hint: after resolving the conflicts, mark the corrected paths
hint: with 'git add <paths>' or 'git rm <paths>'
hint: and commit the result with 'git commit'
```

the `I` commit (merge) solves all those conflicts, but it is not applied and cherry-picking stops

What is the best way out (except having it good organized from the start) ?

---

Edit - added example:

I have

```
* 3b0a2b4 3.line Adam (HEAD, Adam)
*   c04efb0 Just fixed merge from other computer
|\
| * 3e5f111 2.line Adam_a
* | 897bfc3 2.line Adam_b
|/
* 308a3c5 1.line Adam
* 33f3119 === new year ==== (master)
* 436619b 1000.line
.............
* 0a12c01 4.line
* 41d763d 3.line
* dd1feb0 2.line
* 55aa2c2 1.line
* 84b12e9 Point zero
```

Please see, that the branch `Adam` have conflict in it (3e5f111 and 897bfc3 adds respectively line `Adam_a` and `Adam_b` to the same place), which the developer Adam somehow solved in c04efb0 (by writing there something totally different, like `Adam_* # it does not matter` or so)

and I want to add new branch `develop` - that is easy squash of `master`

```
* 75675e1 === new_year === squashed 1.000 lines (HEAD, develop)
* 84b12e9 Point zero
```

and now I want to add branch `feature_1` (over `develop`) with content from `Adam` (but not have to manually solving all those already solved conflicts, I want the merge (4444567) be just the same as on branch `Adam`)

```
* 555567 3.line Adam (HEAD, feature_1)
*   4444567 Just fixed merge from other computer
|\
| * 3334567 2.line Adam_a
* | 2234567 2.line Adam_b
|/
* 1234567 1.line Adam
* 75675e1 === new_year === squashed 1.000 lines (develop)
* 84b12e9 Point zero
```

to get this:

```
* 555567 3.line Adam (HEAD, feature_1)
*   4444567 Just fixed merge from other computer
|\
| * 3334567 2.line Adam_a
* | 2234567 2.line Adam_b
|/
* 1234567 1.line Adam
* 75675e1 === new_year === squashed 1.000 lines (develop)
| * 3b0a2b4 3.line Adam (Adam)
| *   c04efb0 Just fixed merge from other computer
| |\
| | * 3e5f111 2.line Adam_a (Adam_a)
| * | 897bfc3 2.line Adam
| |/
| * 308a3c5 1.line Adam
| * 33f3119 === new year ==== (master)
| * 436619b 1000.line
| * 0a12c01 4.line
| * 41d763d 3.line
| * dd1feb0 2.line
| * 55aa2c2 1.line
|/
* 84b12e9 Point zero
```

(and later I will delete `Adam` and `master` )

Comment: Try `git rebase --preserve-merges`

Comment: If I understand it, `git rebase` changes the existing branches under their names, while I need preserve existing branches and make new one, similar, but with other names. So the result IS duplicate of the origin, which still exists. - in the end I want `jacks_branch` (with 1.000 commits) AND `feature_123` (with 42 commits) to be in the same git repository and to have the same content (and the 'same' last 14 commits, including merges from small branches). Yes, it is duplicity. After some time the `jacks_branch` will be deleted, but not soon.

Comment: I think the way to do that (apologies if I am wrong, I have not confirmed this) is to check out those branches, then do `git checkout -b <duplicate branch name>` and do your rebase. That should leave the original branch untouched.

Comment: I think, that it is, what I am doing. But problem is, that the original branch contains short 'feature branches', but that is result of two people doing similar thing, so the merge ends in conflict solved in the merge commit. And the rebase/cherry-pick stops before it and asks me to solve the conflict interactively. But I would like use as a solution the next commit in line. I will try to specify it better.

Comment: So in the end i just squashed all problematic parts to single commits and the change had happened peacefully. Still I would like solution to this problem.

Answer (score 1):

I think that rather than trying to rewrite history, you (and your team) should focus *now* on using the workflow you want to use going forward. That brings me to my next point, which is that if *you* move forward with a particular git workflow while other members of your team continue to use your current one, you will probably not be successful.

Assuming that the various branches in your repository have not diverged too much, you and your team should start merging and consolidating towards whatever you want your repository to look like, e.g. a master branch and feature branches.

Rewriting history (e.g. with a rebase) is tricky because it means that every commit since the one you're modifying or squashing must also be rewritten, which means that your new versions of those commits no longer match everyone else's "old" versions. When used sparingly on recent history, it can be useful, but rewriting the history of an entire repository and expecting to reconcile that with active development is not something I would ever attempt.

Comment: We all agreed, that the way should be different and I know more about Git, than others, so I should make it be. I will just add the "right' structure to existing repository, duplicating end status in each valid branch in it. They then just `git checkout` the new name and will see the same files and the same last commits and continue to work. I will check some time for commits in obsolete branches and if none came, just delete those branches. If some commit came, I will trace culprit, correct his/its settings and `cherry-pick` the commit where it belongs.

Comment: So after some time, only new structure would be used and old one would be deleted. And we would use short feature branches, which ends squashed in `develop` branch as single working commits (with tests) and the branches itself would be deleted soon after the merge. So everything would be nice, simple and working. But there are some automated processes, and sometimes somebody goes wild in production and the deployment is just checkout (not good and be solved later), so I cannot just throw away everything and on the other hand there is so much of chaos, that slow conversion would be too slow.

Comment: I guess what I'm advocating is not that you should convert *slowly* to the new workflow, but that you should focus on current and future work rather than the long, sordid history of your repository to date. IMO your plan to correct past wrongs will only make your transition harder (especially if you have to put pressure on your colleagues to comply). Generally speaking, there's no reason why "branch soup" can't be merged into something more orderly going forward.

Comment: My plan is just simply squash all the long way, leaving only few commits on `production` (those already deployed and in use), few commits on `develop` (those, where live branches grows out and top) and copy current live branches to 'features', which would end squashed in `develop` as soon as possible, so their ugly-ness will be deleted then. But I need to preserve last few commits in each of those branches, as those commits are used and referenced. And I do not want more work on those 'old' branches, so i need to copy it, to make the transition as simply as checking out new branch.